# Which IPC mechanism is fit for my application

Tags: c++, curl, client-server, ipc, libcurl

I am developing an serve application which does file transfers using a file transfer library say cURL.

The client application will also provide the filename to be transferred.

The client also requires progress information of the filetransfer.

Please suggest which IPC mechanism is best suited for this kind of client server interaction?

Also Can I share Class objects across these two processes?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for shared memory. You can use the shared memory as the content of a object.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest go for Sockect communication. You may have to code bit more, but this is client-server scenario where client server could be on different machine, it will be generic program. Keep in mind how scp works.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you're running both processes on the same box you could go for shared memory. However, this can be awkward to use as you have to synchronize access to the memory and be able to notify the server when the client has written the correct details to the memory.

Because of this you're better off going for a socket approach. It will handle the two way communictation for you and provides a straightforward way for the client to discover the server. Also, if you end up moving the server process onto another machine it shouldn't require too many changes to make it work.